# Using JMS, how can I get the maximum message size for a particular destination?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

Question title is complete but let me rephrase : using Standard JavaEE API, how can I get the maximum message size for a given JMS destination ?

And if not possible, how can I get it from Java code (that's to say using code tied to a particular implementation - Glassfish in my case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximum message size is configurable in the app server, hence it should be accessible from the server's runtime MBean.